# CalendarView not displaying android version 4.1.2

Tags: android-layout

In my app, there is a page for the calendar, and I have on my activity

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/CompanyCalendarCalendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

which is working fine on newer phones, but in android version 4.1.2 that page of the app just goes to a black screen, and in the debug, I see many of the error:

```
[samsung-gt_i8190n-4790f0be6f67b05a]: W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

(the device is samsung-gt_8190n)

Is it just that this version of android does not support CalendarView? If not, what can I use instead?

Please note that this page does not yet have any code on it, and is working fine on a later version of android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a calendarview, I used caldroid, which can be implemented in the layout as a

To implement:
Add the following to build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
```

Then sync.

Then on your layout add a  of roomorama.caldroid

Github:
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid